# How to format the date output of my PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, date, datetime, formatting, format

I have created this script:

```
$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$inbox.Items | foreach {
    "$($_.SenderEmailAddress)%$($_.Subject)%$($_.CreationTime)" |
        Out-File x:\zzz\ccc\test.csv -Append
}
```

I am looking to format the datetime as just the date in UK format.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Assuming `$_.CreationTime` is an actual `DateTime` object: `$_.CreationTime.ToString('dd\/MM\/yyyy')`

Answer (score 0):

The `ToString` function is used to change the format of numbers, dates, etc. [Here's a list of common codes you might be interested in looking at](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.80).aspx).

```
"$($_.SenderEmailAddress)%$($_.Subject)%$($_.CreationTime.ToString('d'))" |
    Out-File x:\zzz\ccc\test.csv -Append
```

Using just one of the letters in the list will give you that specific pattern. If you specify more than one, it takes that to mean that you want a custom pattern. For example, `d` will give you: `8/3/2017` while `yyyy.dd.mm` will give you a custom pattern: `2017.03.08`.

Using a letter multiple times changes how to interpret that specific code. An example for `d` (the current day):

> 1. dd : 14
> 2. ddd : Thu
> 3. dddd : Thursday

That means you can go as ballistic as you want:
 `ToString("dddd MMMM d, yyyy"))`

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Zach's answer, you can use the format operator `-f` in a similar way:

```
"{0:dd}/{0:MM}/{0:yy}" -f (get-date)
```

If you're in the UK you might have luck with the method that lives on datetime objects already

```
$date.ToShortDateString()
```

My machine is set to US english, and it gives me the US version though of m/d/y